# SQL unknown columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, max, average, having-clause

Im new to SQL and am having difficulty with this query:

The average elevation of each Texas county which contains one or more zip code with a population over 20,000.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT county, zip_code, state, AVG(elevation) 
FROM zip_codes 
WHERE state=’TX’  
GROUP BY county 
HAVING population > 20000 
ORDER BY county;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '’TX’' in 'where clause'

But when I select `state` from the `zip_codes` database it is there.

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong quotes? Use these ones: ' (straight ones)

Comment: Don't use e.g. Microsoft Word or other word processing software to create code. They tend to use non-ASCII characters - such as the odd not-quite-apostrophe characters shown above - instead of the standard ASCII values for things like apostrophe, double-quotes, etc. Get yourself a programming editor - there's a lot out there which are free and fully functional. I happen to use jEdit because it's approved at my workplace. There's a TON of other such tools. Find one you like and stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the quote issues is a must-have, as answered by Littlefoot.

However, your query is still invalid Oracle SQL, since:

- the `select` clause has two non-aggregated columns that are not part of the `group by` clause (`zip_code` and `state`)
- same goes for column `population` in the `having` clause, that is neither aggregated nor part of the `group by` clause

For this assignment:

> The average elevation of each Texas county which contains one or more zip code with a population over 20,000.

Assuming that each record in the table corresponds to to a different zip_code (which seems relevant, given that the table itself is called `zip_codes`), you could phrase:

```
select county, state, avg(elevation) avg_elevation
from zip_codes 
where state= 'TX'  
group by county, state 
having max(population) > 20000 
order by county;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using *wrong* single quotes. Should be

```
WHERE state = 'tx'
```

instead of

```
WHERE state = ’tx’
```

Yours are ... where from? Some editor like MS Word or similar, which creates those "fancy" quotes. Well, don't use them.

Apart from that, columns that aren't aggregated should **all** be part of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
group by county, zip_code, state
```

Comment: This is true, but the query is still invalid after fixing the quote issue.

Comment: So true, @GMB. Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT county, zip_code, state, AVG(elevation) 
FROM zip_codes 
WHERE state='TX'
GROUP BY county,  zip_code, state 
where population > 20000 
ORDER BY county;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a data sample it's difficult to understand precisely what's going on, but I'll take a stab at it.

Your assignment says you are to compute "The average elevation of each Texas county which contains one or more zip code with a population over 20,000". Let's break down the elements of the assignment you need to find:

```
Average elevation
  Of each county in Texas
    Which has one or more zip code
      With population > 20,000
```

And we've got a table of zip codes, with county, state, and elevation.

So, OK - first problem: find all the zip codes in Texas:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ZIP_CODES
  WHERE STATE = 'TX'
```

OK, easy so far. Now, limit it to zip codes with a population over 20,000:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ZIP_CODES
  WHERE STATE = 'TX' AND
        POPULATION > 20000
```

Cool - but this gives us an entry for each zip code in the county with a population > 20000. All we care about are the individual counties which have AT LEAST one zip code with a population over 20K. So how about

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNTY
  FROM ZIP_CODES
  WHERE STATE = 'TX' AND
        POPULATION > 20000
```

Great. Now we need to compute the average elevation in each county returned by the above query:

```
SELECT COUNTY, AVG(ELEVATION)
  FROM ZIP_CODES
  WHERE STATE = 'TX' AND
        COUNTY IN (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTY
                     FROM ZIP_CODES
                     WHERE STATE = 'TX' AND
                           POPULATION > 20000)
  GROUP BY COUNTY
  ORDER BY COUNTY
```

And there's your answer.